# Azure Webapp: 'docker: command not found' after I installed docker

Tags: linux, azure, docker, debian

I'm running an App Service on Azure. I can SSH into the Linux terminal.

Linux version: Debian 9.13 (Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch))

I'm getting the message 'docker: command not found' even though I just installed Docker.

I installed docker in this way:

`root@682bfc3257d2:/home# apt-get install docker Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done docker is already the newest version (1.5-1+b1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I was getting the same error even after running `apt-get install docker`.

[image]
[image]

Later, I followed this [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) and could install `Docker` in Azure App Service->SSH.

[image]

Set up the repository

1. Updating the  `apt`  package.

   ```
   1. apt-get update | apt-get upgrade
   2. apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
   ```

[image]
[image]

2. Adding Docker’s GPG key:

   ```
   1. install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
   2. curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg |  gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
   3. chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
   ```

[image]

3. Command to set up the repository:

   ```
   $ echo \
     "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
     "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
      tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
   ```

[image]

***Installing Docker:***

To install latest version of docker, run the below command:

```
apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

[image]

*Running `docker` command to verify:*

[image]

Comment: It helped almost completely. I had to install Compose in a different way. Because I got 'Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin'. I used the manual way mentioned here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-the-plugin-manually 

And the only thing not working yet is the buildx plugin. I get: 
Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin.

Comment: @DirkBroenink, did you try the steps mentioned in this [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_ls/) for buildx.

Comment: There are no steps mentioned in that link, @Pravallika. Thanks for your suggestion.